# scraping hub error python 2.7 while deploying

Tags: python, scrapy

I wrote some spiders that I am trying to deploy on scraping hub. I did:

```
shub login
shub deploy
```

I assume the error below is happening because my spider is written in Python 3.7.3 and scraping-hub uses Python 2.7. Is there a way to deploy it as is, or do I need to convert code to "run" python 2.7?

Note: the error is in a `print` (which I can remove easily) but I do use `f"{}"` in many cases while filling up the scraped items.

Resulting error:

> ```py
>     Deploying to Scrapy Cloud project "55555"
>     Deploy log last 30 lines:
>         _run(args, settings)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 103, in _run
>         _run_scrapy(args, settings)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/crawl.py", line 111, in _run_scrapy
>         execute(settings=settings)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
>         cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 251, in __init__
>         super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 137, in __init__
>         self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 338, in _get_spider_loader
>         return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
>         return cls(settings)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
>         self._load_all_spiders()
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
>         for module in walk_modules(name):
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
>         submod = import_module(fullpath)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>         __import__(name)
>       File "/app/__main__.egg/test/spiders/example.py", line 33
>         print(f"prods:\t{temp}")
> ```

Comment: At github it said: "Requirements = Python 2.7 or above". I guess its not a problem. I merely review your question for improvements. (End of Review).

Answer (score 0):

Install `shub` in your virtual environment (`pip install shub`) so that `shub` uses the same Python interpreter as your spider, and try again.